# How to set the navigation bar button when user taps “More”on UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios8.4

Whenever the user wants to select a new share method or action that isn't listed by default, by tapping the "More" button on the UIActivityViewController generated share sheet, a new view is displayed, As everybody knows.i need to change the bar button on that page                                      [image]

can anybody help me on adding our own bar button as a rightbarbutton item?

Comment: what the answer you need

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need to change the done button position on the navigation bar

Comment: I think is not possible, you can change the tint color only

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik do u know why it is out of bounds ,like in the image?

Comment: is the native delegate methods ,just like mfmailcomposer , in here we can change tint color only , in here i learned two things 1. if you change any default delegate method the apple reject your app, else part we won't customize the delegate methods

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205502/how-to-change-buttons-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik still the question remains why it is coming like that....i found nothing like appearance in my entire application

Answer (score -1):

Try with this. if not you want this ,then explain a little bit more.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```